# Backbone js - Clean up data using regex on collection(models) before passing to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone to populate a dropdown list. Changes to the API have resulted in the data (option labels) coming back with unwanted data e.g "Option Foo - 00011222" instead of "Option Foo"

I'm planning to use regex so that i can only show the first characters before the '-'

What is the best approach to sanitizing data on a collection before rendering to a view.

Should this be done on the view or on the collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the additional data can be safely discarded, you can use [Model.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) to modify the data you receive:

> **parse** model.parse(response, options)
>   parse is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in fetch, and save. The
>   function is passed the raw response object, and should return the
>   attributes hash to be set on the model.

For example, if you want to replace a `label` field:

```
var data = [
    {label: 'Option Foo - 00011222'},
    {label: 'Option Foo2 - 00011222'}
];

var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(data) {
        data.label = data.label.replace(M.regexp, '');
        return data;
    }
}, {
    regexp: /\s*-.*$/
});

var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M
});

var c = new C(data, {parse: true});
console.log(c.pluck('label'));
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/xPJDr/